# Mifare DESFire EV2 Master File AES Authentication

Tags: aes, mifare, des

I am working with Mifare DESFire EV2 card, I am trying to authenticate with the master file using AES Key.

I have achieved the authentication with master file using DES successfully, but when trying with AES using the command INS=0xAA, i get response 0x91AE.

is there any setting for the master file to enable AES Authentication? or only DES is the available authentication with master file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a blank new card, AES is the the wrong cipher. The default cipher is 2K3DES, not AES. You must first change the cipher from the default to AES if you want to use it.